# How to exactly georeference in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

When I georeference a raster image in QGIS, it's always a bit displaced as in the attached image (the cyan polygon is the template, the red border is the georeferenced image), although I try to set the georeference points as exact as possible.

Is there a trick to set the georeference points more exact or maybe move the raster layer a bit? Maybe there is a different software, you can georeference by moving and then import it to QGIS?[image]

Comment: More details please.

Comment: There aren't more details. I need a different way than the georeference tool of QGIS to georeference a raster image, because it produces unprecise results like shown in the attached image.

Comment: For proper georeferencing, you need to add a bunch of reference points, and choose an appropriate method of interpolation. Your picture does not show any points, and we do not know which method you have selected.

Comment: What kind of reference interpolation did you use(bilinear, nearest neighbor, ...). There might be some improvement here. Besides that ether (1) make more accurate GCP points or just recreate the map in QGIS (doesn't look that complicated)

Comment: How many points are you setting to georeference the data and how dispersed are they? I generally find the more points I add (beyond 3 well spaced points) the less accurate the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have good result changing the default transformation settings from Linear to Helmert.

Comment: Well, you need to do that if the raster image and the reference data aren't in the same projection. Linear only tries to move the image to the correct location without transforming ("warping") it.

Comment: I took your advice and got a perfect result, thank you :)

Comment: @simskopf: Then you might want to accept Jakob's hint as the correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the option "From cap canvas" bottun in the "Enter map coordinate" window:

[image]

1. mark point on the image in the georeferencer window- mark specific pixel (1):

   [image]
2. click on the "From cap canvas" button
3. mark the second point on the same pixel (2) in the image inside the QGIS map

this will result with high georeference quality